# Is it possible to change styles for a "Layer Group" in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have a layer group with 2 layers. Each of those layers has a style associated with them that I setup in the LayerGroup Section.

I would like to change "styles" for the Layer Group but it doesn't look like when using a layer group that styles can be changed.  Are there any work arounds that would allow this.  (Outside of having to specificy BOTH layers and then BOTH CQL_Filters, STyles, etc...)

Comment: you could create a 2nd layer group

Comment: Thanks, Thats what I've done to work around this but not real clean.  In my JavaScript code I have to remove first layer from map and add second layer.  It would be much easier if I could jsut change STYLES=second_style verse removing/adding new layers

Comment: I found a ticket osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browser/GEOS-10252 that looks like it's doing what I"m asking.  Looks like it's going to go into Geoserver version 2.21.x  (Not sure when that is anticipated to be released.. I can see documentation updated but it's pointing to the 2.20.x stuff..). But looks like we might be close.

Comment: looks like next week - https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Release-Schedule - you could try out the nightly builds of main to test it before the release.

Comment: Release schedule has been delayed to accommodate the Log4j2 upgrade, not sure when the release is going to be out... I think it was like 2 weeks delay? Definitely the time to try out a nightly build though, and provide feedback before the final release is done.